# ActiveRecord .select .where

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to get `channel` as string from `users` where `id` is random. But I have some problems.
Code:

```
2.2.1 :001 > User.select(:id, :channel).where(:id => rand(1..User.count))
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.`channel` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, channel: "Nickname">]>
```

When I'm trying to display it:

```
#<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000a196388>
```

But I just want to display "Nickname".
Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use then `#first` method like :

```
User.select(:id, :channel)
    .where(:id => rand(1..User.count))
    .first.channel
```

Read the [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) documentation to understand how it works.